# reusing elements in tableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell

I am adding a textfield to each row in tableview and releasing it after adding it to the cell.

I want to reuse when UIButton is clicked.

I tried some methods but it does n't worked.
Help me how to reuse it.

Comment: post your codes here. And what do you mean by  'reuse when UIButton is clicked'

Comment: for eg. Take user name and password. I added the text fields to tableviewrows and a button to navigation controller. when the button on navigation controller is clicked it should print the values given in textfield (i.e.,it is added to tableview cell and released).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do an custom cell view. Subclass the UITableViewCell and use the normal reuse of cells, that is the best way to do it. Improves scrolls on slow devices like iPhone 3G.

Take a look [here](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/).